# Convert Curl to Invoke-WebRequest

Tags: powershell

I have a script code below, its using curl for this operation, i wanna replicate same using Invoke-WebRequest of powershell. how to do it.

```
$FX_USER=$args[0]
$FX_PWD=$args[1]
$FX_JOBID=$args[2]
$REGION=$args[3]
$FX_HOST=$args[4]

$runId=$(curl -k --header  "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8" -X POST -d '{}' -u ""${FX_USER}":"${FX_PWD}"" ""${FX_HOST}"/api/v1/runs/job/${FX_JOBID}?region=${REGION}" | jq -r '."data"|."id"')
Write-Host "runId = $runId"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$FX_USER=$args[0]
$FX_PWD=$args[1]
$FX_JOBID=$args[2]
$REGION=$args[3]
$TAGS=$args[4]
$SUITES=$args[5]
$CATEGORIES=$args[6]
$FX_HOST=$args[7]

Write-Host "user = ${FX_USER}"
Write-Host "region = ${REGION}"
Write-Host "jobid = ${FX_JOBID}"
Write-Host "hostname = ${FX_HOST}" 



$pair = "${FX_USER}:${FX_PWD}"
Write-Host "$pair"
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($pair)
$base64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
Write-Host "$base64"
$basicAuthValue = "Basic $base64"
Write-Host "$basicAuthValue"
$headers = @{ Authorization = $basicAuthValue }
Write-Host "$headers"

add-type @"
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ICertificatePolicy {
    public bool CheckValidationResult(
        ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate certificate,
        WebRequest request, int certificateProblem) {
        return true;
    }
}
"@
$AllProtocols = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]'Ssl3,Tls,Tls11,Tls12'
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = $AllProtocols
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object TrustAllCertsPolicy







$runId=$((Invoke-WebRequest  -Uri "${FX_HOST}/api/v1/runs/job/${FX_JOBID}?region=${REGION}"   -Headers $headers -Method POST  -ContentType "application/json;charset=UTF-8" ) | ConvertFrom-Json  | select -expand data | select -expand id)

Write-Host "runId = $runId"
```

Answer (score 0):

[Have your read up and practiced with the cmdlet and try the examples in the help files to get fully up to speed on it?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6)

```
# get function / cmdlet details
(Get-Command -Name Invoke-WebRequest).Parameters
Get-help -Name Invoke-WebRequest -Full
Get-help -Name Invoke-WebRequest -Online
Get-help -Name Invoke-WebRequest -Examples
```

Have you even tried what you are doing with Invoke-WebRequest to see if it is successful or not? What errors did you encounter.

PowerShell uses curl as a alias for Invoke-WebRequest. They of course are not the same thing and thus cannot replicated identically.

The web cmdlets have been improved PSCore (Windows / Linux / OSX) than they are in PSv5x and below. To make sure you do not run into site connection issues, make sure to use ...

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

...in your code. PSCore is designed to run side by side with Windows PowerShell, it does not replace it.

Using the cmdlet
[cUrl vs Invoke-WebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47364244/curl-vs-invoke-webrequest)

```
$headers = @{
  'X-JFrog-Art-Api' = $apiKey
  "Content-Type" = "application/json"
  "Accept" = "application/json"
}
Invoke-WebRequest -InFile $file -Method Put -Uri "$ARTIFACTORY_HOST/third-party/test/readme.md" -Headers $headers -Verbose


curl -T readme.md "${ARTIFACTORY_HOST}/third-party/test/readme.md " \
-H "X-JFrog-Art-Api: ${apiKey}" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Accept: application/json"
```

You can use curl.exe directly in PowerShell as well, if you choose to do so, [just as you can with any other external exe.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx)